# Random File Name

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i have a folder called MAPS.  I would like when a menu item is selected , in this case its Maps->Random.  That it will randomly select one of the file names in the folder map.  how can i make it random?

Comment: Retrieve all possible FileNames into FileList : TStringList and access with FileList[ Random( FileList.Count ) ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the list of file names in the folder:

```
uses
  System.Types, System.IOUtils;

var
  FileNames: TStringDynArray;
....
FileNames := TDirectory.GetFiles(DirectoryName);
```

And then pick an index at random.

```
var
  Index: Integer;
.....
Index := Random(Length(FileNames));
```

So, your random filename is given by

```
FileNames[Index];
```

Call `Randomize` on startup to ensure that the user doesn't get the same sequence of *random* numbers each time they run the program.

This isn't the most efficient approach since it allocates strings for each file in the directory, and then you use only one. However, it's probably the most convenient and simple approach.

Comment: `uses System.IOUtils, System.Types`

Comment: There is no need to call Randomize, because it is called automatic in newer Delphi Versions :-)

Comment: As an aside, I hate the fact that the designers of `IOUtils` elected to use `TStringDynArray` rather than `TArray<string>`.

Comment: @whosrdaddy `class constructor TPath.Create` in IOUtils happens to do so. I would not rely on that though and still make an explicit call to Randomize.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Application.Initialize forces that

Comment: To get around the "allocate and load all, then use only one enty" problem, you could count the file names, then pick a number in the resulting range 1..no of files, say N, and then scan for the Nth file. This makes you scan twice, though, but the need to hold all filenames in memory vanishes.

Comment: @SirRufo No it does not. That just calls `InitProc`. Which `InitProc` calls Randomize?

Comment: @David: indeed, One can not rely on hidden dependencies! After looking at the code, the only reason why `Randomize` is called in the `TPath` class constructor is for class function `GetRandomFilename`.

Comment: thanks no idea why i did not think of that.. i guess i was looking for a predefined function that would just get one.. :D   Thanks

Comment: @David yes you are right, Randomized is called before Application.Initialize

Comment: @David - that is okay (result type) - those parts probably were developed in different times and had to have different dependencies.
The proper fix would be making TArray<string> and TStringSynArray "assignment-compatible"

Comment: @Arioch'The Well, the proper fix would be to kill `TStringDynArray`. But if that's too drastic then `TStringDynArray = TArray<string>` will suffice.

Comment: @David that still would not fix it for dozen of ad hoc `array of string` vars and `type MyArray = array of string` ad hoc synonims

Comment: @Arioch'The No. All those ad hoc types should be changed to TArray<string>. I have done that in my code base.

Comment: @David Do next step then. Change it in RTL/VCL and in all 3rd-party libraries u use. And repeat on every update. Or it can be fixed one time in one single place - in the compiler.